# RapidJSON library getting a value inside an array by its index

Tags: c++, c, json

```
{"hi": "hellow",
"first":
    {"next":[
            {"key":"important_value"}
        ]
    }

}
```

Accessing RapidJSON inside array:

this works: `cout << "HI VALUE:" << variable["hi"].GetString() << endl;` this will output: `hellow` as expected, the problem is to access inside values like if I want to get "Important_Value", I tried something like this: `cout << "Key VALUE:" << variable["first"]["next"][0]["key"].GetString() << endl ;` but this doesn't work, I want to be able to get the "important_value" by the first item of the array, and in this case it's the `[0]` that is causing error.

How do I do to get it by its index?
I hope it's clear my explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JSON

```
    {"hi": "hellow", "first":  {"next":[{"key":"important_value"}  ] } }
```

Code:

```
rapidjson::Document document;       

if (document.Parse<0>(json).HasParseError() == false)
{
    const Value& a = document["first"];

    const Value& b = a["next"];

    // rapidjson uses SizeType instead of size_t.
    for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < b.Size(); i++)
    {
        const Value& c = b[i];

        printf("%s \n",c["key"].GetString());
    }        
}
```

Will print **important_value**

Comment: this doesn't answer anything fella, make an example off my example with the brackets [ ], the brackets are the problem because it's a automatic position of arrays, the first one is 0, next is 1 and so on... what you did, I already have, try to get the value as in my example, use the same source.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to access nested object in array member. +1

Answer (score 14):

[Update]

By clever work of contributors, RapidJSON can now disambiguate literal `0` from string. So the issue is no longer happens.

https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/issues/167

---

The problem, as mjean pointed out, the compiler is unable to determine whether it should call  the object member accessor or the array element accessor, by literial `0`:

```
GenericValue& operator[](const Ch* name)
GenericValue& operator[](SizeType index)
```

Using `[0u]` or `[SizeType(0)]` can workaround this.

Another way to cope with this problem is stop using overloaded version for operator[]. For example, using `operator()` for one type of access. Or using normal functions, e.g `GetMember()`, `GetElement()`. But I do not have preference on this right now. Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this in the tutorial.cpp file;

```
// Note:
//int x = a[0].GetInt();         // Error: operator[ is ambiguous, as 0 also mean a null pointer of const char* type.
int y = a[SizeType(0)].GetInt(); // Cast to SizeType will work.
int z = a[0u].GetInt();          // This works too.
```

I didnt test it but you may want to try one of these;

variable["first"]["next"][0u]["key"].GetString()

variable["first"]["next"][SizeType(0)]["key"].GetString()

Answer (score 0):

```
auto value = my_array[rapidjson::SizeType(index)].GetFoo();
// replace GetFoo with the type of element you are retrieving, e.g. GetString, GetObject
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access it with brackets, then you can use the following:

```
int i=0;
cout<<"Key VALUE:"<<variable["first"]["next"][i]["key"].GetString()<<endl ;
```

Output: Key VALUE:important_value

It worked for me.